# Can't load Templates after deploying

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, web-deployment

I have a small ember app and I load handlebars templates vía ajax once the app has started. Something like

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  currentPath: '',  
  ready: function(){            
    loadTemplates('hbs/default.hbs'),
    loadTemplates('hbs/checkin.hbs'),
    loadTemplates('hbs/users.hbs')
    ....
```

`loadTemplates` is basically an Ajax call that loads in sync.
While developing, Chrome was unable to load those `.hbs` so I opened it with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option. Everything went fine.

Now I am deplying the app to our server and I can't load it. It goes `404` on every `.hbs` file. Is this a jsonp case?

I don't get it, same server, same policy...

**EDIT**.

When I go to `http://myserver/myproject/hbs` it shows the `403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.` page. I should tell you that my user has admin priviledges.

**EDIT2**

I can't access the `hbs` files on the server. The files are there but it keeps saying `404`. I'm scratching my head here.

is it something to do with the server? It's an IIS 7, the webfolder y set to the default app pool.

Comment: What does the Network tab in the console say is the full path to the resource it's trying to resolve? Have you then tried accessing the resource directly in the browser at the path it shows? What is the response then? It seems to me if you are using relative urls such as `hbs/default.hbs` and not `/hbs/default.hbs` it's likely a 404 is occurring because it's genuinely not there.

Comment: you're right @Scott, it says `http://myserver/hbs/` instead of `http://myserver/myproject/hbs` do you know why is that?

Comment: Do you get forbidden when you go to http://myserver/myproject/hbs/default.hbs?

Comment: No, if I go there its `404`, If I go to the folder /hbs/ I get `403`.

Comment: Do the files exist on the server? Because ultimately if you can't access them directly through the url, then it's not a programming question.

Comment: I did a copy paste, yes the files are definetely there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uff, solved.

The MIME type for handlebars didn't exist on the server. After adding it everything 's fine.